# Evaluate the definite integral $\int_0^{2016} x (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)... (x-2016)\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> $$\int_0^{2016} x (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)... (x-2016)\,dx$$

I have tried integration by parts using calling $f (x)=(x-1)(x-2)... (x-2016)$ but it doesn't help. I can't think of anything else. Please help.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of formatting the equation.

Comment: You would need $2016$ steps to plough through integration by parts! Fortunately there are some shortcuts :) Nice question (+1).

Answer (score 10):

Note that

$$\scriptsize\begin{align}
\int_0^2 x(x-1)(x-2)dx&=\int_{-1}^1 (x-1)x(x+1)dx&=0\\
\int_0^4 x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)dx&=\int_{-2}^2 (x-2)(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2)dx&=0\\
&\vdots\\
\int_0^{2016} x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdots (x-2016)dx&=\int_{-1008}^{1008} (x-1008)(x-1007)\cdots x\cdots (x+1007)(x+1008)dx&=\color{red}0\\
\end{align}$$

The result follows from the antisymmetric nature of the curve
$\scriptsize(x-a)(x-a+1)\cdots x\cdots (x+a-1)(x+a)$.

Comment: Nice use of script size, and good answer..+1

Comment: @Bacon - Thanks! Had to get it to fit, for typographical symmetry :)

Comment: The $+$ signs in the LHS integrands should be $-$ signs.

Comment: @JohnBentin - Yes, thanks! (It still works if the limits are from $-2n$ to 0 though! :))

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** Shift the variable of integration so that the interval is centered at $0$, that is, set $$x = u + 1008 , \qquad dx = du .$$

Alternatively, substitute $$x = 2016 - v, \qquad dx = -dv ,$$ and compare the result with the given integral.

Answer (score 6):

This Definite integral can be evaluated using the property  $$\int_a^b f(x) dx= \int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$$

Lets say that $$I= \int_0^{2016} x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-2016) dx$$

Applying the property above,
$$I= \int_0^{2016} (2016-x)(2015-x) \cdots (-x) $$
$$\implies I= - \int_0^{2016} x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-2016) dx$$

Adding our initial equation to the one we have obtained, we can see that
$$ 2I=0 \implies I=0$$

Comment: Ok thanks all. It was easy, i couldn't see it.